# Javascript variable between two external files

Tags: javascript, function, variables, external

I'm new to JS, and I don't understand why this doesn't work. The following is in a file called `test1.js`

```
var greeting;

function randomGreeting(){
    var greet = new Array("BORING JS TEST ALERT", "EXCITING JS TEST ALERT", "AWESOME JS TEST ALERT");
    var randGreet = Math.floor(Math.random() * greet.length);

    greeting = {
        alert: greet[randGreet]
    };
}
```

In a separate `test2.js` file:

```
alert(greeting.alert);
```

In my HTML I have `randomGreeting()` being called in the body's `onLoad`, and I have `test1.js` loaded before `test2.js`, but I still get `undefined` from the console when test2 is ran. Why?

Comment: When is `randomGreeting` called?

Comment: Whoops, sorry. `randomGreeting` is called in the body's `onLoad`.

Comment: But `alert(greeting.alert)` is not in onload? That means it runs before `randomGreeting`.

Comment: Yea I'd post more of your code.  Sounds like `alert()` runs before the `onload` event handler..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a race condition against test2.js running and the document onload event which fires much later.

You either delay the alert until the variable is set

```
(function(){
   if (typeof greeting == "undefined")
      return window.setTimeout(arguments.callee, 10);

   alert(greeting.alert);
}());
```

if you're not recalling randomGreeting, you can just inline it

```
var greet = new Array("BORING JS TEST ALERT", "EXCITING JS TEST ALERT", "AWESOME JS TEST ALERT");
var randGreet = Math.floor(Math.random() * greet.length);
var greeting = {
    alert: greet[randGreet]
};
```

Or you can change the scripts to use the [defer](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp) attribute

```
<script scr="test1.js"></script>
<script scr="test2.js" defer></script>
<script>
window.onload = function(){
    alert(greeting.alert);
};
</script>
```

Comment: I guess this really highlights the fact that I need to better understand the execution order of scripts and event listeners. If you have a good reference to help me better understand that, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

### Use Immediate Invoking Function:

You could wrap your randomGreeting() in an immediate invoking function code block to get it executed as soon as it's declared and thus your code will work:

```
var greeting;

(function randomGreeting(){
    var greet = new Array("BORING JS TEST ALERT", "EXCITING JS TEST ALERT", "AWESOME JS TEST ALERT");
    var randGreet = Math.floor(Math.random() * greet.length);

    greeting = {
        alert: greet[randGreet]
    };
})();
```

In a separate test2.js file:

```
alert(greeting.alert);
```